# Destiny Engram Chance

Tags: destiny

So I have my first character, a level 15 hunter and I have only got around 3 engrams over the whole game experience. Now I was wondering if higher levels (ex: level 20) would yield a higher chance of receiving an engram or I am just completely unlucky and I need more time to farm/kill enemies.

Comment: The game only really starts when you hit lv20.

Comment: Are you playing strikes, or just doing missions and bounties?

Comment: Engrams are less common than simply getting gear. They become more common at higher levels because they are earned as rewards. As for the drop rate, items are still more common even at higher level.

Answer (score 1):

3 seems reasonable for lower levels. Most engram's you get early on will automatically decrypt into a weapon or piece of armor.

There's no exact chance that anyone knows of, and it changes from time to time. However I can tell you that an hour of doing public events typically nets me 5-10 greens and 1-4 blues. An hour of lvl 28 strikes will typically net me 5-20 blues. An hour of PvP Control will typically net me 2-8 blues.

I've put approximately 300 hours into destiny. In that entire time, I have gotten around 10 legendary (purple) engrams, and 2 exotic (yellow) engrams. That doesn't count engrams that I've purchased.

It does differ depending on conditions, and even then the randomness really governs the drops. I have had times where an hour of strikes has netted me 5 blues, and times where an hour netted me 30.

Comment: Thanks man, I was getting kind of annoyed how I am barely getting any engrams.